# how bagfile avoid to be rewritten

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I try to use bag file to store data, I find the bag file only store the data that I write last time. Last time means the last time to open the bag file and write data. Anybody knows how to add data to bag file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212705/how-bagfile-avoid-to-be-rewritten/) by [YiboLyu](https://answers.ros.org/users/22847/yibolyu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-07-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-07-01**:
I do not know if this is possible. However, you can always save bags with different name and the reproduce them in a sequence with a script.

**Comment by [YiboLyu](https://answers.ros.org/users/22847/yibolyu/) on 2015-07-01**:
Thank you for reply. Yes, I am doing exactly now as you say but I still want to see if adding data is possible. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I find the solution. Just change the bag open mode as
bag = rosbag.Bag('test.bag', 'a')
Mode 'a' means add in the file.

---

Originally posted by [YiboLyu](https://answers.ros.org/users/22847/yibolyu/) with karma: 3 on 2015-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-07-02**:
I'm happy you found the solution. However, your question was incomplete as I assumed you wanted to it from terminal instead of programatically :) How do will you deal with the difference in timestamps? Will the be a problem?

**Comment by [YiboLyu](https://answers.ros.org/users/22847/yibolyu/) on 2015-07-02**:
No. I use it in program not terminal. Actually, in my program, I record two timestamps by myself and I just omit its timestamp. : ) Is it kind of cheating?

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-07-03**:
I don't think that is cheating. Most algorithms will not require the timestamp, other to check that a new message has arrived, or something like that.